# How to retrieve the properties from a constructor with the apply method properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay. I have a simple function that when you click on the **action** button a description will appear in the **id=output** div. The problem is that I think I am using the **apply method** wrong or I misunderstood the use of it. My impression was that you can retrieve properties from functionA and put it in functionB if you express it as **functionA.apply(functionB, arguments)**; . However, when I did that the methods did not get inserted into functionB or bulbStats. Neither did the arguments change when I added the array called **stats** in the second parameter. So basically, I need to know how to insert the methods of bulbPowers into bulbStats, and change the properties with the stats variable. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvs28tyL/) for the code

HTML

```
<body>
  <h3>Bulbasaur does ...</h3>
<div id = "output">
  </div>
  <button id="act">Action</button>
    <button id="sto">Stop</button>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#output{
  border:grey solid 1px;
  width:360px;
  margin:auto;
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;

}
```

Javascript

```
function bulbPowers(){
  this.tackle = () =>{
    let damage = (this.atk * 0.3) +this.atk;
    let msg = `Bulbasaur unleashes a tackle that does ${damage} damage`;
     let m = document.createTextNode(msg);
    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(m);
  }

  this.vineWhip = ()=>{
    let damage = (this.atk * 0.55)+this.atk;
    let msg = `Bulbasaur lets out a dreadful vinewhip that does ${damage} damage`;
     let m = document.createTextNode(msg);
    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(m);
  }
}

function bulbStats( hp, attack, height, weight){
   this.hgt = height ||"3'8";
   this.wgt = weight ||  150;
   this.hp = hp || 100 ;
   this.atk = attack || 10;
}

var stats = [ 156, 24, "4'2",161];
bulbPowers.apply(bulbStats,stats);
var bulbasaur = new bulbStats();


console.log(bulbasaur);
document.getElementById('act').onclick = function(){

  bulbasaur.tackle();
}
```

Comment: You're already using let and arrows, so why not use a class, and if you have to have `stats` as an array.. you can just use spread operator..   https://jsfiddle.net/nvs28tyL/1/

Comment: yeah, but I'm trying to learn how to use the apply method  properly with constructor objects. I know I can use it with class, but I want to use the apply method

Comment: @black_yurizan You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/nvs28tyL/2/

Comment: Are you shitting me, that was the only thing I was doing wrong? Aww man, thanks for letting me know how to do it, I appreciate it

Comment: @cswl, please post this as an answer (relevant details) so OP can accept it and to help future readers.